# OfflineIMAP tells me SQLite isn't installed, even though it is

Tags: osx, python, libraries, sqlite, offlineimap

Whenever I run OfflineIMAP v6.5.3.1 I get an error for every folder (i.e. tag and folder in Gmail) which tells me there was a problem and then right after it tells me:

```
SQLite backend chosen, but no sqlite python bindings available. Please install.
```

This happens for every folder/tag so it's a long error list.

What is causing this? I am on Mac OS X 10.7 and I have installed `sqlite` with `brew install sqlite`, I've also tried `pip install pysqlite`. Of course I have both Python 2.7 and Python 3 installed (`brew install python python3`). So Python 2.7 is accessed using `python` and Python 3 is accessed using `python3`. Think that's the problem maybe?

Any help is appreciated. :)

P.S.: It's the only error it gives me so it seems my config file is OK.

**EDIT:**
List of Python modules:

```
altgraph (0.7.1)
argparse (1.2.1)
bdist-mpkg (0.4.4)
bonjour-py (0.3)
eventlet (0.13.0)
greenlet (0.4.1)
include-server (3.1-toolwhip.1)
localtunnel (0.6.1)
macholib (1.3)
modulegraph (0.8.1)
numpy (1.5.1)
pip (1.4)
py2app (0.5.3)
pyobjc-core (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-Automator (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-CalendarStore (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-CoreData (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-CoreText (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-InterfaceBuilderKit (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-Message (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-PubSub (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-QTKit (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-Quartz (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-ServerNotification (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-WebKit (2.3.2a0)
pyobjc-framework-XgridFoundation (2.3.2a0)
pyOpenSSL (0.12)
PyRSS2Gen (1.0.0)
pysqlite (2.6.3)
python-dateutil (1.5)
requests (1.2.3)
Warning: cannot find svn location for setuptools==0.6c12dev-r85381
setuptools (0.6c12dev-r85381)
Twisted (11.0.0)
vboxapi (1.0)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
xattr (0.6.1)
zope.interface (3.5.1)
```

Comment: If I can't get this working I guess I'll have to go with the file based option? So that it saves my emails in plain text files instead of SQLite files.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [OfflineIMAP software](https://github.com/nicolas33/offlineimap/blob/master/offlineimap/folder/LocalStatusSQLite.py) there is a file called `LocalStatusSQLiteFolder.py`. In this file is a class definition: `LocalStatusSQLiteFolder`, with the following method, `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, name, repository):
        super(LocalStatusSQLiteFolder, self).__init__(name, repository)       
        # dblock protects against concurrent writes in same connection
        self._dblock = Lock()
        #Try to establish connection, no need for threadsafety in __init__
        try:
            self.connection = sqlite.connect(self.filename, check_same_thread = False)
        except NameError:
            # sqlite import had failed
            raise UserWarning('SQLite backend chosen, but no sqlite python '
                              'bindings available. Please install.')
```

This is what's throwing the exception message you're seeing.

#### Solution?

Looking through the OfflineIMAP website I found this page, titled: [OfflineIMAP Manual](https://offlineimap.readthedocs.org/en/latest/MANUAL.html?highlight=sqlite). Specifically in this section: [Synchronization Performance](https://offlineimap.readthedocs.org/en/latest/MANUAL.html?highlight=sqlite#synchronization-performance), the module `python-sqlite` is mentioned as being required. Also there is a guide on how to set this feature up, I'd read through that material and make sure you're doing things as prescribed there.

Comment: I've Googled a lot, and I have read that part of the manual, but that's the *only* mention I see of `python-sqlite` in that manual, and everywhere else they mention the packages I mentioned. Could you please point me to the guide on how to setup `python-sqlite` up? Because I can't seem find it. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Greduan - can you include a list of the python modules? `pip list`. Looking through the source I see `sqlite3` so I'm gonna make the jump that they *meant* sqlite3.

Comment: All right, edited question to contain output of `pip list`. I don't have the `sqlite3` one, I'll install that one and try again...

Comment: @Greduan -   I think that's the one, there may be other modules related to sqlite3 that need installation as well.

Comment: All right. Updated to latest version and running into problems with the SSL certificate, so it may take a while until I report back.

Comment: @Greduan - OK, at least we're making progress 8-)

Comment: OK back, had to downgrade since I couldn't get the SSL certificate working. OK so it seems there's no pip package for `sqlite` or `sqlite3`. I've run `brew install sqlite` and it installs but that still doesn't seem to solve the problem... Guess I will have to go with a text file backend huh?